# memset used for memory allocation?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, memory, memset

i was looking at this example at msdn:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms894209.aspx

```
DWORD dwResult;

MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbiMemory;

// Clear the results structure.
memset (&mbiMemory, 0, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION));

dwResult = VirtualQuery (lpPage,        // Page to examine
                     &mbiMemory,    // Structure for results
                     sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION));

if (sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION) != dwResult)
{

    // Your error-handling code goes here.

}
```

seems like they use memset as a way to allocate memory to mbiMemory. Is it ok? wont i run over some memory this way? thanks!

Comment: Why do you think `memset` is used here to allocate memory? The code does not show that at all. `mbiMemory` is a local struct on the stack and it is filled with zeroes by using `memset`. There is no dynamic memory allocation going on at all.

Answer (score 8):

No, they don't allocate memory, they just reset the struct to contain all zeroes so that it is initialized to some known state and the program behaves in reproduceable manner. Since they only overwrite that struct (`sizeof` is passed as "number of bytes") they won't overrun anything.

Answer (score 6):

Idiomatic coding would be like this:

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbiMemory = {0};
```

The problem with that is that when non-expert C++ programmers read the samples they most likely will not understand that particular syntax. Raymond Chen [wrote about this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050628-07/?p=35183) <strike>recently</strike>way back in 2005.

Comment: -1: The question is tagged as "c", not "c++". This won't work in C (unless MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION has only one member)

Comment: @qbert220 I believe the meaning of that initializer statement to be compiler specific.

Comment: @qbert220: That initializer will work in C just fine.  Even if `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION`.  C++ added the ability for initializers to be completely empty (` some_struct = { };`).

Comment: @David, @Michael: Having checked my books I agree with you. Can't seem to remove my downvote though.

Comment: @qbert220 I've edited the question and you can now remove your downvote should you so wish

Answer (score 0):

No. `INFORMATION mbiMemory` is an [automatic variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable). It's a struct, and it's allocated on the stack. Just like if you'd written `int foo`.

Answer (score 0):

The memory is allocated on the stack by this:

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbiMemory;
```

the memset is clearing the memory that has been allocated to zeros.